# SED's Substituted string is considered as one-line string, whereas it contains newline character

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am testing the **sed** command to substitute one line with 3 lines and, then, to delete the last line. (I could have substituted it with only the 2 first lines, but this is deliberately stated like this to showcase the main issue).

Let's say that I have the following text :

```
// ##OPTION_NAME: xxxx
```

I want to replace the token `##OPTION_NAME` by `##OP-NAME` and surround it by 2 new lines; Like so :

```
// ##OP-START
// ##OP-NAME: xxxx
// ##OP-END
```

To illustrate this, I put this text in a **code.c** file, and the sed commands in a sed script named **script.sed**.
Then, I call the following shell command :

**Shell command**

```sh
sed -f script.sed code.c
```

**script.sed**

```
# Begin by replacing patterns by their equivalents, surrounding them with ##OP-START and ##OP-END lines
s/\(.*\)##OPTION_NAME:\(.*\)/\1##OP-START\n\1##OP-NAME:\2\n\1##OP-END/g
```

### The problem

Now, I add another sed command in script.sed to delete the line containing `##OP-END`. Surprise ! all 3 lines are removed !

```
# Begin by replacing patterns by their equivalents, surrounding them with ##OP-START and ##OP-END lines
s/\(.*\)##OPTION_NAME:\(.*\)/\1##OP-START\n\1##OP-NAME:\2\n\1##OP-END/g

# Last parse; delete ##OP-END
/##OP-END/d
```

I tried `\r\n` instead of `\n` in the sustitution command
`s/\(.*\)##OPTION_NAME:\(.*\)/\1##OP-START\n\1##OP-NAME:\2\n\1##OP-END/g`, but it does not work.

I also tested on `##OP-START` to see if it makes some difference,
but alas ! All 3 lines were removed too.

It seems that sed is considering it as one line !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a surprise, `d` operates on the *pattern space*, not on a per line basis. After the modification with the `s` command, your pattern space contains 3 lines. The content of it matches the expression and gets therefore deleted.

To delete this line from the pattern space, you need to use the `s` command again:

```
s/\(.*\)##OPTION_NAME:\(.*\)/\1##OP-START\n\1##OP-NAME:\2\n\1##OP-END/g$
s/\n\/\/ ##OP-END//
```

About *pattern* and *hold* space: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13

Comment: Interesting ! I've made some tests, and I think I see what you mean. But why you prepended `@@OP-END` by `\/\/` (did not work for me). Instead, I used `s/\n.*##OP-END//` and it worked.

Comment: `\n.*` is fine. Maybe you used tab instead of space, multiple spaces, etc. and therefore my regex didn't match